# Django 1.4 mod_wsgi - 403 forbidden , access to / denied

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

Ive wasted about 3 days trying to get apache working with django and getting very frustrated. 
Ive read

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

The configuration differs between the links and I suspect they are a bit outdated now with django 1.4
The error im facing in the apache log is

> (13)Permission denied: access to / denied

## Environment:

Python 2.62

Centos 6.2 on Windows Azure

Apache/2.2.15

Django 1.4

## Paths:

/home/craig/django/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

## Permissions:

/home/ : drwxrwxr-x

/home/craig/  : drwxrwxr-x

/home/craig/django/ : drwxrwxr-x

/home/craig/django/myproject/ : drwxrwxr-x

/home/craig/django/myproject/myproject/ : drwxrwxr-x

/home/craig/django/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py: -rw-r--r--

## Http.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory /> 
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /home/craig/django/myproject/myproject>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/craig/django/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/craig/django/myproject

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myserver.domain.net
</VirtualHost>
```

## wsgi.py

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/434020/django-1-4-mod-wsgi-403-forbidden-access-to-denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was immediately fixed by disabling SELINUX by running the following command:
setenforce 0

This probably isnt best pratice, but for development purposes it did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded from Django 1.3 to 1.4, I used the daemon process (I wasn't with older versions of Django). This worked for me with Django 1.4 `wsgi.py` files as generated by `createprojet`. Here's a simplified version of one of my configs:

```
Listen 8091

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8091>

  ServerAdmin admin@foobar.com
  ServerName foobar.com

  # Django 1.4 project and virtualenv
  WSGIDaemonProcess foobar python-path=/home/micah/www/foobar.com/foobar:/home/micah/www/foobar.com/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup foobar
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/micah/www/foobar.com/foobar/foobar/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

I should note that Apache was behind an Nginx proxy (hence the IP address for the virtual host) and that I was using virtual environment (hence the `python-path`).